# Rails - configure separate log file for debug, info, and errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Right now, I have my `config.loger` level set to `:debug`, defined in the `config/environnments/production.rb` file. However, this makes errors really hard trying to trace because of the amount of traffic being generated to the production server. I figured it may be easier if I could just simply go to a `log/production_error.log` or a `log/production_debug.log`, `log/production_info.log` file depending on my needs.

I wasn't able to figure out how to do this from the `config/environments/production.rb` file, just from an application controller level.

Is there any way to configure this properly so I can just set it up and not have to worry about adding it to each controller?

Comment: Have you considered configuring a service like Rollbar.com to track and notify you of errors automatically instead of looking at the production log files? There are many reliable services like this - I used Rollbar for free for years but recently started paying $10/year because their service is so useful.

Comment: You would have to create your own logger class or find a logger made by someone else that separates the log files. The default logger is pretty simple by design and does not have any options like this. But as @JeremyWeathers points out in what is a little to close to a product plug for my liking there are better tools that can solve the problem.